# Exibir elemento quando o mouse estiver sobre uma imagem

Tags: html, css

Tenho 4 elementos `<div>` onde elas possuem um componente que só é exibido quando o usuário passa o mouse sobre a `<div>` `container` (esta que possui `class="thumbanil"`) porem quando passo o mouse sobre o conteúdo oculto o mesmo fica visível, este comportamento não deveria acontecer pois onde fica o conteúdo oculto esta posicionado a outra `<div>` container (esta que possui `class="thumbanil"`).

**Como deveria ficar:** O conteúdo que está oculto deverá ser exibido somente quando o mouse passar sobre a `<img>` thumbnail e permanecer visível em quanto o mouse estiver sobre a `<div>` `container` (esta que possui `class="thumbanil"`).

**O que já fiz (mas não funcionou):** Fiz com que o elemento oculto só ficasse visível quando o mouse passa-se sobre o thumbnail porém assim que o mouse saia do thumbnail para entrar no conteúdo oculto o conteúdo oculto (agora visível) voltava a ficar oculto, logo voltei ao esta anterior do código.

Código HTML:

```
                <div class="col-md-8 section span7 text-center">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="assets/images/projetos/thumbnail.png" alt="Site Pessoal">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <p><strong>Site</strong></p>
                            <p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info gray gly_medium" id="site-imagens" title="Veja imagens">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info gray gly_medium" title="Acesse o site">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="assets/images/projetos/thumbnail.png" alt="Video Site">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <p><strong>Video Content Site</strong></p>
                            <p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info gray gly_medium" id="video-imagens" title="Veja Imagens">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info gray gly_medium" title="Acesse o site">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="assets/images/projetos/thumbnail.png" alt="Video Site">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <p><strong>Video Site</strong></p>
                            <p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info gray gly_medium" id="video-imagens" title="Veja Imagens">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info gray gly_medium" title="Acesse o site">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="assets/images/projetos/thumbnail.png" alt="Video Site">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <p><strong>Video Site</strong></p>
                            <p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info gray gly_medium" id="video-imagens" title="Veja Imagens">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info gray gly_medium" title="Acesse o site">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>
                                </a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Código CSS:

```
.thumbnail{
    display:inline-block
}

.caption{
    opacity:0; 
    transition:opacity .5s;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#fff;
    width:308px;
    margin-left:-5px
}

.thumbnail:hover .caption{ 
    opacity:1; 
    z-index:1
}
```

Imagem que demonstra o defeito:
A seta vermelha esta no lugar do mouse, note que o mouse esta (aparentemente) em cima do thumbnail da `<div>` abaixo porem está realmente em cima do `caption`.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo no [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hk3ynf0p/), gerado pelo user @IsraelSousa.

Comment: Consegues reproduzir isto num jsFiddle? não vejo nenhuma div `container` no teu HTML.

Comment: a div container é esta com `class="thumbanil"` irei ser mais especifico na pergunta.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer, testei aqui em um jsfidle e está funcionando da forma que você quer se é o que entendi.

https://jsfiddle.net/hk3ynf0p/

Comment: O hover está aparecendo enquanto você está com o mouse posicionado sobre o item.

Comment: @IsraelSousa note que quando passa o mouse sobre a parte superior da imagem é exibido o conteúdo oculto da `div` superior. isto não deveria acontecer.

Comment: Para mim o comportamento é o mesmo independentemente de que parte da imagem o mouse faz hover... não é assim para tí? que browser usas?

Comment: Quando faço o hover da `<div class="caption">` ela fica visível porem ela está oculta abaixo de outra `<div>` e quando passo ou mouse por cima da   parte superior da `<div>` que esta abaixo é exibido o capition da div superior, ex: no fiddle passe o mouse na parte superior da imagem do carangueijo, é exibido é exibido o `caption` da imagem do thunderbird. Faça com que o fiddle fique com uma dimensão pequena, para que haja uma quebra de linha e tenha uma div sobre a outra

Comment: Eu entendi, quando aponta o mouse para o <p> ou <strong> ele aparece, quando o que ele queria era somente quando apontasse para a imagem.

Tenta fazer isso:
.caption:hover{

       display:none;
}

Comment: Ok, com a quebra de linha já percebi o problema. Soluciona juntando visibility hidden/visible? -> https://jsfiddle.net/hk3ynf0p/2/

Comment: @Sergio Sim funcionou.

Comment: @Sergio, já havia validado a solução do Fernando quase no mesmo instante, poste sua resposta para que possa lhe ar os 10 pontos de rep. e para que outros users a vejam no futuro.

Comment: @RicardoHenrique, acho que encontrei uma solução melhor acompanhe a [edição da resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67661/2998).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problema**

O que está acontecendo é que ao utilizar `opacity`, para esconder/exibir o elemento, ele só está ficando transparente (`opacity: 0`) e não está saindo da view, então ele continua ocupando seu espaço na tela, sendo assim ao passar o mouse na parte superior da imagem abaixo, o :hover é considerado na `<div class="thumbnail">` superior, pois ela está naquela área.

**Solução**

O que você pode fazer é trocar a forma de esconder/exibir o elemento de `opacity` para `display` (display: block; = visível e na view e `display: none;` = invisível e fora da view), assim o elemento quando invisível não ocupara espaço na tela não sendo considera para o evento `:hover` em seu *parent*. Ficando algo similar a isso:

```css
.caption{
    display: none; /* trocado de opacity */
    transition:opacity .5s; /* dessa forma essa transition não funcionaria */
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#fff;
    width:308px;
    margin-left:-5px
}

.thumbnail:hover .caption{ 
    display: block; /* trocado de opacity */
    z-index:1
}
```

[Exemplo online jsFillde.](http://jsfiddle.net/hk3ynf0p/1/)

**[Edit 1] (Solução melhor aplicando somente o `:hover` sobre a `img`)**

Há uma forma que achei o resultado melhor utilizando `visibility` como sugerido na [resposta do @Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67673/2998), e aplicando o `:hover` apenas a imagem (`img`), pois nas soluções anterior se você fosse sobre a imagem, e fosse descendo até o caption (`div.caption`), ele continuava sendo exibido, mesmo que o mouse já estivesse fora da image, pois ele estava sobre o `thumbnail` (`div.thumbnail`), onde estava o evento `:hover`.

Então está solução consiste em:

- Adicionar o evento *hover* apenas a image (`img`);
- Aplicar o estilo do *hover* ao seu próximo elemento irmão;
- Manter o efeito do `transction`;

Sendo o seguinte:

```css
.thumbnail {
  display: inline-block
}
.caption {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 3s;
  /* aumentei o tempo para poder ser visto o transaction */
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 308px;
  margin-left: -5px
}
img:hover +.caption {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="http://davidnaylor.org/temp/thunderbird-logo-200x200.png" alt="Site Pessoal" />
  <div class="caption">
    <p><strong>Site</strong>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info gray gly_medium" id="site-imagens" title="Veja imagens">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info gray gly_medium" title="Acesse o site">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/71/Quebec_citadelles_200x200.png" alt="Video Site" />
  <div class="caption">
    <p><strong>Video Content Site</strong>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info gray gly_medium" id="video-imagens" title="Veja Imagens">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info gray gly_medium" title="Acesse o site">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="http://horoscopo.ego.globo.com/img/horoscopo.ego.globo.com/icones/signos/gemeos-g.png" alt="Video Site" />
  <div class="caption">
    <p><strong>Video Site</strong>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info gray gly_medium" id="video-imagens" title="Veja Imagens">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info gray gly_medium" title="Acesse o site">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="http://horoscopo.ego.globo.com/img/horoscopo.ego.globo.com/icones/signos/cancer-g.png" alt="Video Site" />
  <div class="caption">
    <p><strong>Video Site</strong>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info gray gly_medium" id="video-imagens" title="Veja Imagens">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info gray gly_medium" title="Acesse o site">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Exemplo online jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/hk3ynf0p/4/)

Comment: +1, mas se o problema é ocupar espaço na tela, eu acho que o ideal era fazer `height: 0`, `width: 100%` e `overflow: visible` pra fazer o elemento sempre “visível” (ainda que transparente) sem ocupar espaço.

Comment: Sim @ctgPi, há varias alternativas, para ocultar um elemento da view, só tem que ver qual a mais adequada para a situação. E da forma que coloquei a `transaction` que havia não funcionará mais. Mas há alternativas para mante-lá de forma diferente.

Answer (score 2):

Outra solução para além do que o Fernando sugeriu é adicional `visibility` pois assim evita sobreposição de elementos quando o Browser tentar perceber qual o elemento sobre o qual está a pairar (hover).

Assim juntando `visibility: hidden;` à classe sem `:hover` e `visibility: visible;` à classe com `:hover` também soluciona o problema.

**jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hk3ynf0p/2/**

Comment: Correto, e como disse em outro comentário: ainda há varias outras opções para esconder/exibir um elemento com css, que funcionariam para esse cenário. É questão de verificar a que melhor se adequá ao cenário da aplicação. =D