# Por quê o transition não funciona?

Tags: css3

A div `#sub` devia fazer uma transição de opacidade ao passar o mouse sobre `#item`, mas não funciona. Só dá certo quando eu tiro o `display: none` Como se resolve isso ?

```css
  #item,#sub{
   height: 40px;
   width: 300px;
   padding: 0px;
  }
  #item{
   background-color: red;
   position: absolute;
  }
  #sub{
   display: none;
   opacity: 0;
   background-color: yellow;
   margin-top: 40px;
   position: relative;
   transition: opacity 1s linear 0s;
  }
  #item:hover #sub, #item #sub:hover{
   display: block;
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 1s linear 0s;
  }
```

```html
  <div id="item">
   <div id="sub">
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `transition` não funciona com o display, qual é realmente seu problema já que ele fica escondido com o `opacity: 0`?

Comment: Eu vou usar isso em um menu. O problema é que o `opacity: 0` não esconde direito. Se passar o mouse por cima o menu ainda está lá e ainda cobre outras partes da página. Preciso que ao passar o mouse pelo item abra um submenu com transição e quando tirar o mouse ele suma totalmente.

Comment: Carlos combina o `opacity` com `visibility` e aí já não vai sobrepor. Podes completar este jsFiddle para reproduzir o problema que descreves quando usas `opacity`? http://jsfiddle.net/wunafgug/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode remover o `display`, e utilizar `visibility`, assim o elemento não vai continuar na tela e a `transition` irá funcionar, como já citei [aqui em outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67661/2998).

Acompanhe o exemplo:

```css
#item,
#sub {
  height: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#item {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
#sub {
  /*display: none;*/
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  transition: opacity 1s linear 0s;
}
#item:hover #sub,
#item #sub:hover {
  /*display: block;*/
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s linear 0s;
}
```

```html
<div id="item">
  <div id="sub">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado ! Funciona perfeitamente.